# How to convert C# datetimes into Python datetimes with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, python, datetime, protobuf-net

I've serialized an array of C# `DateTime.Now` objects using `protobuf-net` and opened the file in Python with the proto file(struct_pb2.py) of its message structure.

```
// The struct definition in C#

    [ProtoContract]
    public struct struct_tick
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public uint[] arr_currentIndex;

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string[] arr_currentType;

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public DateTime[] arr_currentTime;   // <- for DateTime.Now objects

        public struct_tick(byte size_index, byte size_type, byte size_time)
        {
            arr_currentIndex = new uint[size_index];
            arr_currentType = new string[size_type];
            arr_currentTime = new DateTime[size_time];
        }
    }
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message struct_tick 
{
  repeated uint32 arr_currentIndex  = 1;
  repeated string arr_currentType   = 2;
  repeated google.protobuf.Timestamp arr_currentTime = 3;
}
```

It opens well in Python, but how can I convert C# datetime objects into, for example, Python datetime objects correctly? What makes me confused is that what's shown in the file's datetime array.

```
>>> struct = struct_pb2.struct_tick()
>>> with open(filename, "rb") as f:
>>>     struct.ParseFromString(f.read())

>>> lst_time = [ time for time in struct.arr_currentTime]
>>> lst_time[:5]
[seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 335624000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 335624000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 335624000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 335624000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 335624000
]

>>> lst_time[-5:]
[seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 337636000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 337636000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 337636000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 337636000
, seconds: 1573571465
nanos: 337636000
]
```

When I read the same file in C#, the very first datetime object represents 21:59:39.7450630, and the very end object represents 23:38:50.3848014, which means there is a gap of almost 2 hours. But what's shown in Python is totally different.

Is it because I used `DateTime` when serializing and used `google.protobuf.Timestamp` when deserializing? How can I convert them correctly?

**ADDED**

This is the callback function that receives data and writes it into an array in its struct:

```
static void Handler_Real(string szCode)
{
    string code          = REAL_TR.GetData("Out", "sym");
    string currentType   = REAL_TR.GetData("Out", "cg");
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (dic_codeToTRstructCounter[code] == arraySize)
    {
        dic_codeToTRstructCounter[code] = 0;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dic_codeToTRfilename[code], FileMode.Append))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(fileStream, dic_codeToTRstruct[code]);
        }
    }

    dic_codeToTRstruct[code].arr_currentIndex[dic_codeToTRstructCounter[code]]  = dic_codeToTRCounter[code];
    dic_codeToTRstruct[code].arr_currentType[dic_codeToTRstructCounter[code]]   = currentType;
    dic_codeToTRstruct[code].arr_currentTime[dic_codeToTRstructCounter[code]]   = currentTime;

    dic_codeToTRstructCounter[code] += 1;
    dic_codeToTRCounter[code] += 1;
}
```

This is how I read the file in C#, which works fine.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    struct_tick str = Serializer.Deserialize<struct_tick>(fileStream);

    for (int startNum = 0; startNum < str.arr_currentIndex.Length; startNum++)
    {
        string str_print = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {3}", str.arr_currentIndex[startNum],
                                                          str.arr_currentType[startNum],
                                                          str.arr_currentTime[startNum].ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff"));
        listBox1.Items.Add(str_print);
    }
}
```

This is how I read the same file in Python

```
def convert_TRtoArray(filename):
    struct = struct_pb2.struct_TR()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        struct.ParseFromString(f.read())

    lst_currentIndex  = [  indexNum for indexNum in struct.arr_currentIndex  ]
    lst_currentType   = [  type for type  in struct.arr_currentType ]
    lst_currentTime   = [  time for time in struct.arr_currentTime ]
```

And when I check `lst_currentTime`, although the C# program had received data for 2 hours, the values are like the above.

Comment: as a side note: `struct struct_tick` looks ... dangerous to me; this is a mutable struct, which is almost always a bad idea

Comment: @Marc Gravell Thank you for the advice. I'll look it up and see if there's a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use:

```cs
[ProtoMember(..., DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
```

on your `DateTime` / `TimeSpan` usages; this makes protobuf-net use the "well known" timestamp and duration layouts instead of the default format. The reason it doesn't do this automatically is that they (timestamp/duration) didn't exist back when protobuf-net first had to decide on *some* layout for them.

Note, however, that adding this is a breaking change: the layouts are not compatible.

If you *need* to use the legacy layout, they are described/defined in [`bcl.proto`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/Tools/bcl.proto).

Alternatively, in protobuf-net v3, there are explicit types for timestamp / duration, if you prefer.

---

Given the discussion (comments), frankly it looks like you are either not populating the array correctly, or are leaking that array between contexts. Testing locally, *it looks fine* - the following demo shows it working (with your `struct_tick`), including a breakdown of the binary data that shows seconds/nanos that look correct.

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var payload = new struct_tick(2, 2, 2);
        payload.arr_currentIndex[0] = 12;
        payload.arr_currentIndex[1] = 14;
        payload.arr_currentType[0] = "abc";
        payload.arr_currentType[1] = "def";
        payload.arr_currentTime[0] = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 21, 59, 39, 745, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        payload.arr_currentTime[1] = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 23, 38, 50, 385, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, payload);
        var hex = BitConverter.ToString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(hex);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var clone = Serializer.Deserialize<struct_tick>(ms);
        foreach(var time in clone.arr_currentTime)
            Console.WriteLine(time); // writes 12/11/2019 21:59:39 and 12/11/2019 23:38:50

        // hex is 08-0C-08-0E-12-03-61-62-63-12-03-64-65-66-
        //        1A-0C-08-CB-D6-AC-EE-05-10-C0-98-9F-E3-02-
        //        1A-0C-08-8A-85-AD-EE-05-10-C0-C4-CA-B7-01
        // 08-0C = field 1, 12
        // 08-0E = field 1, 14
        // 12-03-61-62-63 = field 2, "abc"
        // 12-03-64-65-66 = field 2, "def"
        // 1A-OC = field 3, length 12
        //    08-CB-D6-AC-EE-05 = field 1, 1573595979 = seconds
        //    10-C0-98-9F-E3-02 = field 2, 745000000 = nanos
        // 1A-OC = field 3, length 12
        //    08-8A-85-AD-EE-05 = field 1, 1573601930 = seconds
        //    10-C0-C4-CA-B7-01 = field 2, 385000000 = nanos
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct struct_tick
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public uint[] arr_currentIndex;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string[] arr_currentType;

    [ProtoMember(3, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
    public DateTime[] arr_currentTime;   // <- for DateTime.Now objects

    public struct_tick(byte size_index, byte size_type, byte size_time)
    {
        arr_currentIndex = new uint[size_index];
        arr_currentType = new string[size_type];
        arr_currentTime = new DateTime[size_time];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you mean like this?: ```[ProtoMember(5, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]``` But even when I fixed the line like you code, the error still remains. ```>>> lst_time[0] seconds: 1573607798 nanos: 373981000```, ```>>> lst_time[-1] seconds: 1573607798 nanos: 379555000``` Do I aslo need to fix the ```proto``` file for Python?

Comment: @maynull can you be specific as to what error you are referring to? I don't see an error, so I want to be absolutely certain I know what the question is there; what are you seeing in Python?

Comment: @maynull specifically, all of the dates shown in the question are identical - 1573571465 is 2019-11-12T15:11:05+00:00 (give or take some milliseconds from "nanos"). Can you show how you generated this data? do you have some C# that shows what you did here? Happy to investigate (I'm the library author), but I need to be able to repro what you're seeing. Without knowing your timezone, I can't be sure about much, but it looks very odd that they're all the same. Are you sure you're setting the array contents correctly? Do you have the raw binary payload (base-64/hex/whatever) I can look at?

Comment: @maynull see my code update above which shows it working fine; can you show what you're doing, i.e. a minimal repro that shows you getting the output you're discussing?

Comment: @ Marc Gravell Thank you for the great library and help! I ended up just using ```DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks``` and it works fine with Python. I updated my question though and added some additional code. If you think there's no error in my code, I can send you the binary file.

Comment: @maynull I can't comment on whether there is an error in your code, as you haven't shown us the interesting bits, i.e. where you populate the array

Comment: @maynull I see the update; that code looks ... fun, but ultimately what you need to do is look at *what is in the array just before you serialize*. I don't think the contents are what you think they are. As a side note: dictionary lookups are cheapish but not free - if you're using the same lookup on multiple rows, you should *usually* hoist that result into a local

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I overlooked it and have changed quite a bit of my code. Could you please recommend any books or methods from which I can learn how to avoid this kind of mistakes?

Comment: @maynull you'd need to be specific: which mistake are you referring to?

Comment: Such as looking up the same dictionary key repeatedly or things that make my code look fun :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use DateTime in binary serializable streams like Protobuf. It is better to convert DateTime values to something else, like epoch time or even string, and then use serialization on the epoch time or string values. Otherwise, you'll not be able to restore the content of this field correctly.

Comment: I agree here. Convert to epoch or string in C# (easy). Serialize (easy). Convert from epoch or string to DateTime in Python (easy). All easy steps. Otherwise, you jump down a crazy rabbit hole.

Comment: @Old Schooled @Michael Kokorin Thank you for the comments. I think that converting ```Datetime``` into ```string``` is expensive and want to avoid the process if possible.

Comment: note that protobuf-net can be configured to silently use `timestamp` / `duration` for `DateTime`/`TimeSpan`, making it just work